# High CPU usage when Capture image by OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, c++-cli

I'm writing an application simply capture image from camera using openCV (3.4.1), C++ Visual Studio 2013. The code is:
[image]

Camera resolution is 3480*2880. All things are OK except the CPU usage is too high (~30%) while if I run Camera app of Windows 10, it is just 1 to 2%.
The CPU usage is not decrease even when I release the cap variable.
Why and what is solution? Thank you!

Comment: Can you check how many threads/cpu cores the windows app is using compared to yours?

Comment: this won't account for the cpu usage but you can init your frame outside of the loop and not reinit each time

Comment: @RakshithGb Sorry, I don't know how to check it :(

Comment: @chris I tried but there is nothing difference :(

Comment: @MạnhHùng Task Manager->Performance Tab->CPU, then right click on the right pane "change graph to->logical processors". This shows you how much % of each core is being used.

Comment: @RakshithGb: thanks for instruction, 4 cores usage are almost the same in both cases

Comment: If its similar how are you saying its 30% on opencv and 2% on windows app?

Comment: I mean in case of windows app, it's 2% and devided equally on 4 cores. And in my app all 4 cores usage are the same too ( 30% )

Comment: Maybe if you launch app from VS you use debugging config, so part of debbuging process going on might have influence on cpu usage. Have you tried release configuration and launching app without attached debbuger?

Comment: Please show your code, not a picture of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally know the reason. My PC is 64bit but I built my code in 32bit platform.